# Using jquery mousewheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, mousewheel

I download jquery plugin "jquery.mousewheel.min.js", but i dont know,  how use this plugin.
for example how to make:
if are running scroll wheel up, in console write: "UP",
else in console write: "DOWN" ?

Comment: Look it up in the DOCs for that plugin....

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```
$(window).mousewheel( function(e, delta){
     console.log( delta > 0 ? "UP":"DOWN");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't post another question as an answer.

```
var repeat = true;
$(window).mousewheel( function(e, delta){
  if (repeat) {
    console.log( delta > 0 ? "UP":"DOWN");
    repeat = false;
  }
});
```

Just a quick example to your further question.

If you need more help please use the site as intended / read the FAQ's etc if you don't know.

Comment: No, not this, i interest: not have this plugin own option, for disabling self functionality after defined numbers of mousescroll rotation ?